# How to access data in android app from MySQL and display even in offline mode?

Tags: android, mysql, xml, sqlite

I am new in android development. I am developing android app for news portal. I want my users to be able to read news even when there is no Internet connection, somehow similar to twitter feed. I need advice about connecting server data from SQLite. I see two options for now: connecting directly to MySQL or generating XML data in server in /rss page and synchronize using scripts. Which one will be better? Or is there any other option?

Comment: Retrieve the data from online MYSQL, then insert those data into SQLite for offline use, the data between SQLite and online MYSQL must be always the same

Comment: @cwfei Thank you. just want to confirm about SQLite, will it display news  in offline (No Internet)? Or I need to use different cache technique for it as well?

Comment: SQLite is stored in device, which mean you can retrieve the data offline

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is best solution for this problem. We need to put synchronization technique between SQLite and MySQL.